# How do I upgrade to IIS 7 in order to run ASP.NET application?

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7

On the [IIS download page](http://www.iis.net/download/All) there is no one installer just a lot of items that could be installed.  What do I need to install to run a ASP.NET application? I'm running Windows 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIS is part of Windows.
Go to Programs and Features and click Turn On or Off Windows Components

All of those downloads are optional addons that you probably don't need.

Comment: I turned IIS on and it did install. It is IIS 6 and it is not running correctly. I was thinking to install IIS 7 instead. My options are to try to repair IIS6 or install IIS 7 so I was wondering how I can upgrade to IIS 7.

Comment: Main question is how to upgrade to IIS 7? Is it part of Windows update? Is it something that I need to download and install myself? It would be good to know for  people who are trying to upgrade to IIS 7.

Comment: Windows 7 includes IIS 7.5.  It is completely impossible to have IIS 6 on Win7.  You don't need to do anything.

Comment: omg. you right. i was looking at the wrong place. i do have iis 7.5 :/